Can't replicate the behaviour of loss calculation in keras
I am working on a semantic segmentation problem where I have an input x ( CT image) to a deep learning model of shape (batch_size,1,256,256) and an output of shape (batch_size,2,256,256) where the first channel represents an output mask (bone mask), and the second represents a second output mask ( lesion mask). I am using a combined loss function for every channel output , which is a combination of wighted BCE and soft dice loss both focussing on the foreground pixels :
class Custom_Loss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self,w1 = 0.3, w2 = 0.7 , w3 = 0.4, w4 = 0.6, w5 = 1.6 , reduction="sum_over_batch_size" ):
        """
        w1 : weight for the bone loss contribution to the total loss.

        w2 : Weight for the lession loss contribution to the total loss.
        
        w3 : Weight for the soft dice loss contribution to the combined loss.  

        w4 : Weight for the BCE contribution to the combined loss. 

        w5: Weight for the foreground pixels in the BCE loss
        
        """
        self.w1 = w1
        self.w2 = w2
        self.w3 = w3
        self.w4 = w4
        self.w5 = w5
        self.reduction = reduction
        
        super().__init__(reduction = reduction)

    def bce(self,y_true, y_pred):

        epsilon = 1e-8  # Add small epsilon to avoid log(0)
        
        # Compute the total number of pixels
        N = y_true.shape[1] * y_true.shape[2]
        
        # Compute the BCE loss per image 
        bce_loss = (-1 / N) * tf.reduce_sum((self.w5 *y_true *  tf.math.log(y_pred + epsilon)) + ((1 - y_true) * tf.math.log(1 - y_pred + epsilon)),axis = (1,2))

        # Average the loss over the batch
        #bce_loss = tf.reduce_mean(bce_loss)
        

        return bce_loss
    
    def soft_dice_loss(self,y_true, y_pred):
        epsilon = 1e-8  # Add small epsilon to avoid division by zero

        # Calculate the numerator and denominator 
        numerator_dice_coef= 2 * tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=(1, 2)) + epsilon
        
        den_dice_coef = (tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_true, axis=(1, 2))) + (tf.reduce_sum(y_pred * y_pred, axis=(1, 2))) + epsilon

        # Dice coefficient per image in the batch
        dice_coef =  numerator_dice_coef / den_dice_coef

        # Average Dice coefficient over the batch
        #mean_dice_coef = tf.reduce_mean(dice_coef)

        
        return 1 - dice_coef

    
    def combined_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):

        loss =  (self.w3 * self.soft_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred) ) + (self.w4 * self.bce(y_true, y_pred))

        return loss
        
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):        

        bone_pred = y_pred [:,0,:,:]
        lesion_pred = y_pred [:,1,:,:]

        bone_ground_truth = y_true [:,0,:,:]
        lesion_ground_truth = y_true [:,1,:,:]


        #loss = (self.w1 * self.combined_loss(bone_ground_truth, bone_pred ) ) + (self.w2 * self.combined_loss(lession_ground_truth, lession_pred) ) 
        # Compute combined loss for bone and lesion masks
        bone_loss = self.combined_loss(bone_ground_truth, bone_pred)  # Shape: (batch_size,)
        
        lesion_loss = self.combined_loss(lesion_ground_truth, lesion_pred)  # Shape: (batch_size,)
        
        # Total loss per sample
        # Use tf.multiply for weighted sum
        weighted_bone_loss = tf.multiply(self.w1, bone_loss)  # Shape: (batch_size,)
        weighted_lesion_loss = tf.multiply(self.w2, lesion_loss)  # Shape: (batch_size,)
        # Add weighted losses
        total_loss = weighted_bone_loss + weighted_lesion_loss  # Shape: (batch_size,)

 

        
        # Store loss components for logging
        #self.last_bone_loss = tf.reduce_mean(bone_loss)
        #self.last_lesion_loss = tf.reduce_mean(lesion_loss)
        
        return total_loss

I am following the keras documentation where the call function returns the loss per sample. Now I wrote a custom callback to log the validation loss components ( for every mask, bone and lesion) as well as the total loss, as follows :
# Callback for logging loss components at the end of each epoch for the validation data
class LossLoggerCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, loss_fn, validation_data):
        """
        Callback to log loss components for validation data at the end of each epoch.

        Args:
            loss_fn: Custom loss function (instance of `CustomLoss`).
            validation_data: Validation dataset (can be a tf.data.Dataset).
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn
        self.validation_data = validation_data

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # Initialize lists to accumulate losses
        total_losses = []
        bone_losses = []
        lesion_losses = []
        
        # Initialize a counter to keep track of the total number of samples
        total_samples = 0
    
        # Iterate over all batches in the validation data
        for x_val, y_val in self.validation_data:
            batch_size = x_val.shape[0]  # Get the batch size
            
            # Make predictions
            y_pred = self.model.predict(x_val, verbose=0)
    
            # Extract bone and lesion predictions and ground truths
            bone_pred = y_pred[:, 0, :, :]
            lesion_pred = y_pred[:, 1, :, :]
            bone_gt = y_val[:, 0, :, :]
            lesion_gt = y_val[:, 1, :, :]
    
            # Compute combined loss for bone and lesion (this gives a batch-wise loss)
            bone_loss = self.loss_fn.combined_loss(bone_gt, bone_pred)  # Shape: (batch_size,)
            lesion_loss = self.loss_fn.combined_loss(lesion_gt, lesion_pred)  # Shape: (batch_size,)
    
            # Apply weighting as in `call`
            weighted_bone_loss = tf.multiply(self.loss_fn.w1, bone_loss)  # Shape: (batch_size,)
            weighted_lesion_loss = tf.multiply(self.loss_fn.w2, lesion_loss)  # Shape: (batch_size,)
    
            # Total loss per sample in the batch
            total_loss = weighted_bone_loss + weighted_lesion_loss  # Shape: (batch_size,)
    
            # Accumulate batch-wise losses for averaging later
            total_losses.extend(total_loss.numpy())  # Add individual losses per sample
            bone_losses.extend(bone_loss.numpy())  # Add individual bone losses
            lesion_losses.extend(lesion_loss.numpy())  # Add individual lesion losses
    
            # Update total number of samples processed
            total_samples += batch_size
    
        # Compute the mean loss across the entire validation dataset
        mean_bone_loss = np.sum(bone_losses) / total_samples
        mean_lesion_loss = np.sum(lesion_losses) / total_samples
        mean_total_loss = np.sum(total_losses) / total_samples
    
        # Print the results for the current epoch
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}: Validation Bone Loss = {mean_bone_loss:.4f}, "
              f"Validation Lesion Loss = {mean_lesion_loss:.4f}, "
              f"Validation Total Loss = {mean_total_loss:.4f}")
    

The batch size used is 4 , so the shape of one batch in the validation is (4,2, 256,256) for y and for x it is (4,1,256,256) . Like you see in the custom loss class, i am using the reduction sum_over_batch_size. When I train the model in a multi-gpu environment :
 with strategy.scope():
        loss_fn = Custom_Loss()   
    # Initialize the model
        model= create_model() 
        model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-4,beta_1 = 0.999, beta_2 = 0.999),
                            loss= loss_fn,
                            metrics=[IoU]
                            )
    val_loss_logger = LossLoggerCallback(loss_fn, validation_data=val_dataset)
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_io_u', mode='max', verbose=1, patience=40)
    mc = ModelCheckpoint('/kaggle/working/best_model.keras', monitor='val_io_u', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    # Train the model

    history = model.fit(x = train_dataset,
                        batch_size= batch_size,
                        validation_data = val_dataset,
                        epochs= epochs,
                        steps_per_epoch= steps_per_epoch,
                        callbacks=[es,mc,val_loss_logger]) 

I get:
Epoch 1/100
237/237 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 1s/step - io_u: 0.1837 - loss: 272.1821
Epoch 1: val_io_u improved from -inf to 0.00000, saving model to /kaggle/working/best_model.keras
Epoch 1: Validation Bone Loss = 0.6672, Validation Lesion Loss = 0.6553, Validation Total Loss = 0.6589
237/237 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 443s 1s/step - io_u: 0.1842 - loss: 271.8742 - val_io_u: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 83.1071
Epoch 2/100
237/237 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 1s/step - io_u: 0.3941 - loss: 56.6352
Epoch 2: val_io_u did not improve from 0.00000
Epoch 2: Validation Bone Loss = 0.5375, Validation Lesion Loss = 0.5063, Validation Total Loss = 0.5157
237/237 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 339s 1s/step - io_u: 0.3941 - loss: 56.5627 - val_io_u: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 19.8229
        

Why Validation Total Loss returned by the callback is not equal to val_loss returned by keras. I think I have a misunderstanding regarding how keras calculates the loss using the reduction sum_over_batch_size. I want the loss returned by the callback to be identical to that calculated by keras.
The loss function I am using is :
Loss = w1 * Loss_combined_bone_mask + w2 * Loss_combined_esion_mask
where,
Loss_combined_bone_mask = w3* soft_dice_loss(y_pred_bone,y_true_bone) + w4 * BCE(y_pred_bone,y_true_bone) 

and
Loss_combined_lesion_mask = w3* soft_dice_loss(y_pred_lesion,y_true_bone) + w4 * BCE(y_pred_lesion,y_true_bone) 

